# Why shouldn't I use the equality operator for objects

Tags: java

I have this book about Java and it is telling me if I use relational operators for objects such as strings it will turn out as false. Even if two strings have the same literal value. I tested this, yet true was printed. Could someone explain why this is?

```
String y = "Not null";
String x = "Not null";

            if(x == y)
                System.out.println("True");
```

Comment: have you tried searching on SO, this has been answered many times here.

Answer (score 2):

Both `Strings` are interned in the String pool so `x` and `y` refer to the same Object. The expression would not evaluate to `true` if you did.

```
String y = "Not null";
String x = new String("Not null");
```

Since `Strings` are immutable many methods typically return new `String` `Objects`. This is why its recommended to compare content using the `.equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

The strings are interned in the string pool and it will return the reference of the string object that is already interned in string pool(since they are equal).That is why in your case, it is evaluated to "true".